# View NFTs owned by wallet with ERC721URIStorage contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I have a pretty basic contract that allows people to mint NFT's. I'm able to check the balance of the total amount of NFT's the user owns relative to the initial mint contract:

```
connectedContract.balanceOf(web3React.account).then((d) => {
  console.log(parseInt(d))
})
```

Is there a way I can show which NFT's the wallet owns that is only relative to the contract address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual code should only show you the balance of NFT owned by the account on your contract.

```
connectedContract
```

Appears to be your contract. So the Balance is related to that contract.

If you did not implement the Enumerable set. To get all the NFT's of an account you would have to loop over them and call

```
   connectedContract.ownerOf(token_id).call()
```

An example;

```
let balance = await connectedContract.balanceOf(web3React.account)
let i = 0
let supply = await connectedContract.totalSupply();

for(i=0;1< supply ;i++){
// this will check each nft owner
// i is the id of each nft.

// this will return the owner address
let owner = await connectedContract.ownerOf(i);

// if owner == msg.sender then we know he owns this token id

}
```

I strongly recommend that you take a look at the openZeppelin Enumerable contract that provide an easier way of going trough a user NFT balance.

To understand what each OZ extension add to the ERC721 you can visit this link.

[OZ Contracts](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721)

You want to import the required extensions in your contract.

For what you want to do you can use

```
IERC721Enumerable
```

It will essentially provide you with exactly what you want!
The process is similar.
You get the balance, and you can get the index of each token based on the balance.

Comment: I get an error when trying to call `totalSupply()`. Says it's not a function.

Comment: Edited with the link to the OZ Library. Pick and choose the one with the function you like!

Comment: Got it. I'm trying to understand how to implement `IERC721Enuymberable`. I'm doing `contract MakeNFT is ERC721URIStorage, IERC721Enumerable` but I get a type error: `Contract "MakeNFT" should be marked as abstract.`

Comment: Your almost there. But this topic if for another questions. Maybe you should mark this one as accepted and try with a new question!